# How do you handle instantiating a large number of interconnected component objects?

Tags: design, object-oriented-design, refactoring, constructors

I'm currently refactoring our instance startup code, which is currently a 2,000 line mud method. The issue is that that method needs to create a large number (>50) of components/service objects, each with their own dependency requirements on other created components. Something of the style

```
var service1 = createService1()
var service2 = createService2(service1)
var service3 = createService3(service2, service1)
...
var service20 = createService20(service4, service6, service2.obj(), service15)
service20.initSomeThings(service16, configParam)
var service21 = createService21(service2, service6, service20, service19)
```

I'm having problems disentangling this into something sensible. There's a certain amount of splitting out I can do, but at some point it's just a single list 'create all the things in some kind of dependency order' with so many cross-object references they can't be separated out.

**What's the best way to go about making this more sensible?** ie more segregated into separate methods, and doesn't need a 1,000-line method to wire everything together. I don't really want to go down the injection framework route, as that hides the dependency order (we've got a few objects where things have to be constructed in a specific order). The services themselves need to be left as-is, but I can create builders etc. Is there another approach I can take to refactor it, other than slowly trying to pick bits off?

Comment: When you write *"I don't really want to go down the injection route"*, you mean you don't want to introduce a DI *container*, right? Because what we see in the question *is* dependency injection - a.k.a. [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) a.k.a. "DI without a DI container".

Comment: If your main argument against a DI container is construction order, there are ways to make this explicit. Like creating dependencies between the components that need to be ordered, or just create them manually and add them to the container as instances.

Comment: Best way is subjective.  You can:  Refactor what exists today, it is actually not that bad as it is just a bunch of statements or as you have put it a list of things to do.  So, just refactor that into smaller lists instead of one giant one.  OR use a dependency injection framework which is designed for this sort of thing.  But you will have to pick a framework that can take in your current situation and understand how it works, etc.  At this point, a DI framework is a bigger undertaking than refactoring what is there., as you have said you can do it in small chunks over time.

Comment: @thecoop is almost everything really a "Service" or did you just use that term for convenience?

Answer (score 4):

A concatenation of a long list of service instantiations and injections ("wiring up" code) is not a problem per se. It should be simple and not error-prone, as long as any real logic is kept out of this code. A DI container would probably do the same, just hide the complexity, but not reduce it.

However, I would recommend to strictly separate the initialization from any control-flow. Even a block like

```
 var service20 = createService20(service4, service6, service2.obj(), service15)
 service20.initSomeThings(service16, configParam)
```

makes me wonder why the call to `initSomeThings` is not moved into `createService20` - these two calls seem to belong together in sequence, and "initSomeThings" seem to belong to the full creation of the service. Such things should not be buried in some long method where there is some risk that a future refactoring could bring them out of order.

So in short, long initialization methods are ok as long as they stay simple. And "simple" means "really simple" - no "if", no "for", no specific method call where one could mix-up the order.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but the separation of create() versus init() could be to separate out the heavy lifting...  Constructor versus Initialization  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414471/initialize-vs-constructor-method-proper-usage-on-object-creation

Comment: @JonRaynor: createService20 is a function, not a constructor. And I am not suggesting to merge the code inside of initSomeThings somwhere else, I am suggesting to have *one* function "createService20" which may call the constructor of service20, then call initSomeThings, just the same order as it is shown in the question now, only in a way where the "wiring up" code is clearly separated from any other code.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to make choices that limit the scope of variables. This limits what is going on. Leaves you with less to keep in your head.

The nicest readable way to do this remains one of the hardest to write: think of good names.

```
func trinityService()
  var service1 = createService1()
  var service2 = createService2(service1)
  return createService3(service2, service1)
```

Conversely, make choices that limit the need to use meaningless names:

```
var service20 = imATwentySomethingBuilder(
  createService4(), 
  service6, 
  createService2().obj(), 
  createService15()
)
  .withService16(createService16())
  .withConfigParam(configParam)
  .build()

var service21 = createService21(
  createService2(), 
  service6, 
  service20, 
  createService19()
)
```

Done this way objects that only get passed once never get a variable name. With this, there are fewer names to think of, makes clear what you can forget as you read this, and clearly shows connections that span across code groups.

Works much better if you take the time to give your create service functions meaningful names.

It's also worth considering if the object graph you're constructing is well designed. Every problem has a certainly level of irreducible necessary complexity. But is very easy to let your solutions complexity grow beyond that. As you simplify how you express your solution see if you can't see how to simplify the actual solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to show the code using the created services? Differently said with the level of details from the question and excluding builders that have already been mentioned is difficult to answer this question 'cause builders seems to be the most fit alternative to those factory methods.

Maybe there are changes that could be implemented with the code using the services that could pose a different setup and instead of...

```
var service1 = createService1()


service1.doService()
```

...to have something different to...

```
var doService1 = ...

doService1()
```

That is a hierarchy of services where `service21` inherits from `service20` that inherits from `service19` that... and so on shifting from composition (HAS-A relation) to inheritance (IS-A relation).